# ASPNETDB management tools

Tags: asp.net, membership, aspnetdb

Is there any tools to manage deployed ASP.NET application's aspnetdb.mdf file similar to Visual Studio's WSAT ("hummer-globe" button)?

Installations of the Visual Studio and SQL Managment tools on the server are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Enable ASP.NETWebAdminFiles Outside Visual Studio](http://www.jedatu.com/techblog/archives/2005_12_01_index.html)

...

1. Create a virtual directory that points to the web admin files.

   This is what I did:
   VirtualDirectory: ASP.NetWebAdminFiles
   MappedTo: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles
2. Modify the properties of the virtual directory so that it is running under ASP.NET 2.0. (Properties > ASP.NET)

   NOTE: if you are running 1.1 and 2.0 applications on the same server or site, you may have to set up a separate application pool for the 2.0 sites. If you get the notice, "Application Unavailable" then that is why.
3. While you are there, remove anonymous access to that virtual directory.
4. After that, you will be able to connect to the web admin tools using the following url syntax

   http://localhost/ASP.NETWebAdminFiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=XXX&applicationUrl=/YYY

...